# a function that takes a list of integers as a parameter and returns a list of running totals

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I have this function in python, and this function computes the sum of the integers in the list.

```
def runningSum(aList):
    theSum = 0
    for i in aList:
        theSum = theSum + i
    return theSum
```

result:

```
>>runningSum([1,2,3,4,5]) = 15
```

what I'm hoping to achieve from this function is to return a list of running totals.
something like this:

```
E.g.: [1,2,3,4,5] -> [1,3,6,10,15]
E.g.: [2,2,2,2,2,2,2] -> [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when `numpy.cumsum` does it for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appending the running sum into a list in a loop and return the list:

```
>>> def running_sum(iterable):
...     s = 0
...     result = []
...     for value in iterable:
...         s += value
...         result.append(s)
...     return result
...
>>> running_sum([1,2,3,4,5])
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Or, using [`yield` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement):

```
>>> def running_sum(iterable):
...     s = 0
...     for value in iterable:
...         s += value
...         yield s
...
>>> running_sum([1,2,3,4,5])
<generator object runningSum at 0x0000000002BDF798>
>>> list(running_sum([1,2,3,4,5]))  # Turn the generator into a list
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

If you're using Python 3.2+, you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

where the default operation in `accumulate` with an iterable is 'running sum'. Optionally you can also pass an operator as needed.

Answer (score 0):

def runningSum(aList):
    theSum = 0
    cumulative = [ ]
    for i in aList:
        theSum = theSum + i
        cumulative.append(theSum)
    return cumulative

Comment: the question already has an accepted answer and your answer doesn't provide any new information